# Which is the best way to handle GtkMenu activate callback?

Tags: gtk

I have created a GtkMenu with 10 GtkMenuItems in it, and attached `activate` event to each menu item, but in callback function how should I get to know which menu item was actually selected?

I have added Call back to GtkMenuItem as follows:

```
   gtk_signal_connect_object( GTK_OBJECT(menu_items), "activate",
                              GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(on_option_selected),
                              (gpointer)GINT_TO_POINTER( i ) );
```

and my call back function is as follows:

```
gboolean on_option_selected( GtkWidget *widget, gpointer user_data );
```

And tried to convert user_data as follows but getting garbage.

```
gint selected_index = GPOINTER_TO_INT( user_data );
```

Thanks,
PP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `gtk_signal_connect_object()`, it's deprecated and replaced by `g_signal_connect_swapped()`. You get garbage, because with both of those functions, the `instance` and `user_data` are switched around. So you are actually converting the pointer to `menu_items` to an integer. Use `g_signal_connect()` like unwind says.

However, since you're probably just going to do a `switch(selected_index)` after that, I'd recommend writing one callback function for each menu item (e.g. `on_new_selected()`, `on_open_selected()`, `on_save_selected()`, etc.) and connecting each one separately.

Comment: chosen this as write answer cause i was doing this wrong gtk_signal_connect_object

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use the `gpointer user_data` argument to the callback to encode this, somehow.

You might for instance pass an enum, using the `GINT_TO_POINTER()` and `GPOINTER_TO_INT()` macros to convert back and forth. The enum might be something like

```
enum { FILE_NEW, FILE_OPEN, FILE_SAVE, FILE_SAVEAS, FILE_QUIT };
```

or similar. The connect (assuming recent GTK+ 2.x) should look like this:

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(item_saveas), "activate", G_CALLBACK(on_option_selected), GINT_TO_POINTER(FILE_SAVEAS));
```

Or you can go all out and use `GtkAction`s, but that might feel like a bit too much engineering, depends on the number of commands you need to work with.

Comment: Tried with GINT_TO_POINTER() and GPOINTER_TO_INT() with enum but i am getting garbage in call back function when i convert user_data to int. Why this might be happening? Please See updated question.